# Php pdo statement vs MsSQL escaping?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Similar questions have probably been asked before, and sry for that. Need to be sure that i protect from SQL injections correct.

I have just converted my php sql statments to pdo statments. For the old sql queries I used to use `mysql_real_escape_string`, `strip_tags()`, and maybe `htmlenteties()`(not sure if  id did html).

Is it necessery to use anything like this in the pdo statments. Have heard some places that this is not necessary in pdo. Whats true/false ?

And: I have always used to write the queries like the first example below:

```
SELECT `id` , `password` FROM  `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'
SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'
```

Is the example 1 more safer(from sql injections) than example 2 or is it just wasted time doing it ?

Comment: The usual comment at this point: Don't use the `mysql`-extension as this is outdated and it's going to become deprecated. Use `MySQLi`, or `PDO_MySQL` instead.

Comment: *Using either `strip_tags` or `htmlentities` **is wrong** and was **never correct***. `mysql_real_escape_string` was actually designed for "preventing SQL injection attacks", other objections aside .. I *highly recommend* placeholders, however, as they are adopted by every other major language DB-access library I know of. (And supported by both mysqli and PDO.)

Comment: @KingCrunch: There it is :). Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using PDO you should be using prepared statements with parameters. There are some examples in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
```

If you use this approach then there is no need for escaping strings.

Answer (score 1):

They say you don't need to escape strings in PDO because they use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). If you're just using the PDO `query()` method like in mysql, that's no more secure than just using mysql. As for the examples you've given, they're both equally **unsafe**; they're both equally vulnerable to injection (and they're *very* vulnerable to injection). On a tangential point, the `mysqli` extension has one advantage over `PDO` in the sense that you *cannot* carry out multiple SQL statements over one `mysqli_query()`. This offers some (not full) protection against some (again, not all) injection attempts, especially the ones to make new superusers and the like.